# Docker - use the same URL inside the container and outside

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-network

I have a docker container running an open source identity server UI.  This consists of several web applications, and I am running them from the same docker container.

One web application, calls an API endpoint in another web application to get a config file.  It then does a redirect to a URL found in that config file.  The config file is dynamically generated using the domain name in the request.

I make a call from my local host, to the exposed port.  This page then calls another webapi using the docker-compose service name for the URL: ex: https://**webapi2**/well-known/openid-configuration.  This returns a config file with URLs that use webapi2 as the domain.
This causes a browser redirect to https://**webapi2**/singin.  This fails, because my localhost does not know about wepapi1, it needs to use uses localhost:44310.

Comment: Will you know the domain in advance? you could configure your local hosts config file to map webapi2 to localhost.

Comment: I will know it, but I am trying to avoid configuration outside of docker.  Our goal is provide the docker-compose file to other developers that will have very little knowledge of dock,er and will not have access to edit their hosts file.

Comment: but will the other developers always be running a local docker? I.E targeting localhost? or they will be reaching to the docker via some other domain name to reach the server hosting the container?